# How can I get in my logger, the duration of each hibernate query in ms

Tags: java, hibernate

I would have to display in my console log, the duration of each Hibernate query.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on this article. http://www.basilv.com/psd/blog/2008/hibernate-and-logging

It seems it describes exactly what you need. I hope it is still relevant fore newer versions of Hibernate since hibernate moved to SLF4J. In this case you should perform appropriate configuration of SLF4J instead of Log4j

Answer (score 1):

[log4jdbc](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/) and [log4jdbc-remix](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc-remix/) provide extensive logging for JDBC connections, statements, and result sets. These projects provide wrappers around your JDBC driver to do the logging.